# When working remote, would cycling to my co-working space count towards the "50% journey to work" requirement for UK Cycle Scheme?

Tags: united-kingdom, commute

I was hoping to use the Cycle Scheme at my workplace as it's pretty much the only benefit they provide that applies to me. However, I work remotely and only appear in the office every 1.5 months on average. I travel there by train and I'd want to get a folding bike so I can take it on the train and use it to get to/from the train station. But it's still quite rare.

I do however not work from home, instead using a co-working space I pay for myself. As such if I cycled to the co-working space - would that count towards the "50% of journeys with this bike has to be done for work" rule?

Comment: This question is off-topic - it is asking about rules and regulations.

Comment: You should really ask your employer. And you should ask the question over email, so you have a paper trail of their response.

Comment: @StephanBranczyk Generally agreed - but in practice, almost all UK employers doing Cycle to Work outsource it to a 3rd party provider so you may as well just ask the provider instead.

Answer (score 1):

These would count as "qualifying journeys" So long as you're meeting the requirement of work purposes being > 50% of the use of the bike yes. There's no requirement for it be your "main" place of work that you're travelling to.